# Compose LazyColumn select one item

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-list

I want to select one item of my LazyColumn and change the textcolor.
How is it possible to identify which item is selected?

Code:

```
val items = listOf(Pair("A", 1), Pair("AA", 144), Pair("BA", 99))
var selectedItem by mutableStateOf(items[0])
LazyColumn {
    this.items(items = items) {
        Row(modifier = Modifier.clickable(onClick = {selectedItem = it}) {
            if (selectedItem == it) {
                Text(it.first, color = Color.Red)
            } else {
                Text(it.first)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Depending how I save it (with remember or without) they just highlight both if I click on one and not just the one I clicked the last.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use the the [**`.selectable`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/selection/package-summary.html#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).selectable(kotlin.Boolean,%20kotlin.Boolean,%20androidx.compose.ui.semantics.Role,%20kotlin.Function0)) modifier instead of `.clickable`

Something like:

```
data class Message(val id: Int,
                   val message : String)
val messages : List<Message> = listOf(...))

val listState = rememberLazyListState()
var selectedIndex by remember{mutableStateOf(-1)}
 
LazyColumn(state = listState) {
        items(items = messages) { message ->

            Text(
                text = message.message,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .background(
                        if (message.id == selectedIndex)
                            Color.Red else Color.Yellow
                    )
                    .selectable(
                        selected = message.id == selectedIndex,
                        onClick = { if (selectedIndex != message.id)
                             selectedIndex = message.id else selectedIndex = -1})
            )
        }
 }
```

In your case you can use:

```
var selectedItem by remember{mutableStateOf( "")}
LazyColumn {
    this.items(items = items) {
        Row(modifier = Modifier.selectable(
            selected = selectedItem == it.first,
            onClick = { selectedItem = it.first}
                )
        ) {
            if (selectedItem == it.first) {
                Text(it.first, color = Color.Red)
            } else {
                Text(it.first)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that with your solution, all the item views will be recomposed every time the selection changes, because the lambdas passed in `onClick` and `content` (of `Row`) are not stable (https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/lifecycle#skipping).

Answer (score 13):

Note that in the accepted answer, all the item views will be recomposed every time the selection changes, because the lambdas passed in `onClick` and `content` (of `Row`) are not stable (https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/lifecycle#skipping).

Here's one way to do it so that only the deselected and selected items are recomposed:

```
@Composable
fun ItemView(index: Int, selected: Boolean, onClick: (Int) -> Unit){
    Text(
        text = "Item $index",
        modifier = Modifier
            .clickable {
                onClick.invoke(index)
            }
            .background(if (selected) MaterialTheme.colors.secondary else Color.Transparent)
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(12.dp)
    )
}

@Composable
fun LazyColumnWithSelection(){
    var selectedIndex by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
    val onItemClick = { index: Int -> selectedIndex = index}
    LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    ){
        items(100){ index ->
            ItemView(
                index = index,
                selected = selectedIndex == index,
                onClick = onItemClick
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Note how the arguments passed to `ItemView` only change for the items whose selected state changes. This is because the `onItemClick` lambda is the same all the time.

Comment: You use the `.clickable` method in your example. Will it also work with `.selectable` like in the other answer?